# Installing vpython on replit

Tags: python, vpython

I go to packages and I search for vpython and I click install. It notifies that "vpython is installed" but it does not show up as installed.

Comment: _but it does not show up as installed_ Does not show up **where**, exactly?  Can you stare this exact output?

Comment: It does not show under the packages tab in Replit as installed

Comment: I don't know anything about replit, but I can point out that the vpython module would normally be in Lib/site-packages/vpython. Have you looked there?